# RegEx - Testing for 9 adjacent identical numbers

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to test a string (in java) for 9 adjacent identical numbers ... I can test for adjacent identical numbers - but only the next adjacent number ....

```
boolean result = string.matches("/([0-9])\1/g");
```

I want to match 9 characters - anyone able to help me ?

Thanks

EDIT : Some examples

```
"1111111111" should match

"222222222" should match

"3311111111133" should match

"1234567890" should not match
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this regex: `([0-9])\1{8}`

Comment: note: will only `find` in "3311111111133" but not `match` it as requested - missing ".*" at the start and the end of the expression.

Comment: @Carlos, What's the difference between match and find?

Comment: @Carlos - yep discovered that !!! thanks ... i used matcher and the find method ... thanks

Comment: @polishchuk - match checks to see if the string exactly matches the string (ie is 9 identical characters) on the other hand find searches the string for the pattern

Comment: I found this site quite helpful for Java RegEx testing -> http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html

Comment: @ManseUK, I don't understand... In string `3311111111133` provided regex will match `111111111`

Comment: @ManseUK, In .NET we have method `Regex.IsMatch`. For provided regex and `3311111111133` it will return `true` and for `1234567890` - `false`.

Comment: @ManseUK, May be it is Java specificity?

Comment: @Kirill -  The remaining characters (position 3 onwards) should not be identical i.e. 1111111, 2222222, etc.  how to check 3311111111133 is false and 111111111  is true.

Answer (score 3):

Java Greedy quantifier:

`X{n}` machtches:   X, exactly n times

X would be any number = `[0-9]` and n would be 9

```
([0-9]{9})
```

edit:

This will match 9 identical numbers:

```
([0-9]\1{8})
```

`[0-9]` machtes any number

`\1` is the first match, which is performed

`\1{8}` matches 8 times the first match

Comment: is this going to work for the following string 1111111111 ... where the string is 10 characters ?

Answer (score 0):

I found Kirill Polishchuk answer fine and good. However in rare case if you have to print 9 adjacent characters which are separated by space ( like in a text file), you can do the following:

Input:

```
1111111111 4444444444 4455555555558899 567833333333339
```

The regex may be modified as follows:

`'([0-9]) ?\1{8}'`     If you have only one space between columns. 
or

`'([0-9]) *\1{1}'`    If you have uneven number of spaces between columns.

If you want to use with grep you can do it this way:

```
grep -E '([0-9]) ?\1{8}'
```

or

```
grep -E '([0-9]) *\1{8}'
```

Hope this helps.